# How to set password for a user using hash in /etc/shadow on Solaris

Tags: solaris, useradd, passwd, shadow

As part of a new build, I am tasked with creating user accounts on new Solaris server. I have to use the user accounts in an existing Linux server, and set the same password for each user on the Solaris server.

How can I set passwords on Solaris using the existing hash in `/etc/shadow` on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

If it's Solaris 11.3 (and i assume that you are using the most current version, when it's a new build) you can use passwd -p    , you have just to check if the hashing is compatible and use the correct identifier of the hash algorithm at the beginning between two $ $ ... (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/concept-23/index.html)